# Doctrine 2 composite primary key with auto increment

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

In our database we have tables which have no single auto-increment primary key but instead a composite one, which may or may not include an auto-increment field as the first field for that primary key.

For example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gen_5_23`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gen_5_23` (
    `id_azienda` int(10) unsigned NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `id_sede` int(10) unsigned NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `revisione_documento` int(10) unsigned NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `premessa_generale` text,
    `flag_stampa` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_azienda`,`id_sede`,`revisione_documento`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_revisione_documento_gen_5_23` FOREIGN KEY (`revisione_documento`, `id_azienda`, `id_sede`) REFERENCES `agews_revisioni_documenti` (`revisione_documento`, `id_azienda`, `id_sede`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gen_5_23_consumi`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gen_5_23_consumi` (
    `id_consumo` int(10) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_azienda` int(10) unsigned NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `id_sede` int(10) unsigned NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `revisione_documento` int(10) unsigned NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `consumo` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `unita` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `valore` float(11,2) NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_consumo,`id_azienda`,`id_sede`,`revisione_documento`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_main_gen_5_23_consumi` FOREIGN KEY (`id_azienda`, `id_sede`, `revisione_documento`) REFERENCES `gen_5_23` (`id_azienda`, `id_sede`, `revisione_documento`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The key in gen_5_23_consumi is defined as is 'cause there are procedures in our webapp which would blindly take a row, change only id_azienda or id_sede or revisione_documento and then re-insert it, in this way the row would be valid, as it would not be if the primary key was only id_consumo.

We're considering to start using doctrine 2 for database management, but I do not understand from the docs how would you implement such an entity, if it is ever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible but not out of the box. You can have composite key as primary keys for your entities: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html but auto increment implementation should be done in your code because of

> Every entity with a composite key cannot use an id generator other
>   than “ASSIGNED”. That means the ID fields have to have their values
>   set before you call EntityManager#persist($entity).

To emulate auto increment behavior you can have sequence table with id as the auto increment PK and create an entity for this table. Add relation from your main entity to entity that represents auto increment sequence, see class ArticleAttribute from the page above, your code should be very similar:

```
Class Gen523consumiAuto
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $id;
}

Class Gen523consumi
{
    /** @Id @OneToOne(targetEntity="Gen523consumiAuto") */
    private $idConsumo;

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    private $idAzienda;

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    private $idSede;

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    private $revisioneDocumento;
}
```

Comment: How would you suggest doing the auto-increment implementation? Since our database is MySQL, I could do something like `SELECT MAX(id_consumo) FROM gen_5_23_consumi` and then add 1 to that result, but still this would not be advisable, would it? 'Cause in the meantime there could be another insert changing the last id..

Comment: I updated the answer to be more clear. You can check example from documentation. D2 will take care about data consistency because every flush is in one transaction.

Comment: I will check the docs as you suggest, thanks for your advice =)

Comment: I've checked the docs, but I think my case is somewhat different from the ArticleAttribute example: the PK of `gen_5_23` for example is a FK that does not refer to 3 distinct tables, but to a single table for which the PK is `revisione_documento, id_azienda, id_sede`, and from D2 docs I do not really understand how to "tell" this to the entity...

Comment: Gen523consumiAuto takes care about auto increment, Gen523consumi is your entity, fields that should be parts of PK have @Id notation

Comment: Problem with the `Auto` class approach is that it may create duplicate IDs in `Gen523consumi`.  Example:  `Gen523consumi` already has 1, 2, 3.  If you begin `Gen523consumiAuto` with key 1, you will begin to generate duplicate IDs in `Gen523consumi`. You have to take extra care to keep keys in sync.

Comment: ^^ that is to say that `Gen523consumiAuto` is a "hack" that can work but is not a good solution

Answer (score 0):

As of now you cannot do composite (primary, foreign) keys with AUTO INCREMENT option.

You will have to use your own code to select MAX Key from your table.

then set MAX + 1 on your Entity's id.